# Issue with Jquery calendar when going live

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi all i have developed a calendar from here http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html in my application which was working fine in locally. But when i am hosting the files i am unable to display the calendar can any one tell what might be the problem

I found another interesting one i.e when i am having `master page` i am unable to load the script

Here is the link for the one which is having `Master page`

http://myusapayroll.com/Demo/DemoTest.aspx

The one which works fine with out master page is here

http://myusapayroll.com/Test/Test.aspx

Can any one suggest me what to do

Comment: magic? could you give as a url or something to your code? Or could you post your code?

Comment: Not without more information. My first guess would be to fire up fiddle and see if the script file is 404'ing from  bad reference. You did use the `<script url="@Url.Content(...)" ></script>` Url helper right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably because in your rendered page I can see your doing this

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtHiredate').datepick({showOnFocus: false, showTrigger: '#calImg' });
```

but your actual textbox control id is

```
ContentPlaceHolder1_txtHiredate
```

so you need to change your code to and it should work

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtHiredate').datepick({showOnFocus: false, showTrigger: '#calImg' });
```

but try not to hard code the id but instead use ClientID in asp.net

Comment: Works well but in local i am unable to find if i use per the later one

Comment: How can i use Client ID as Per said

Comment: this is a good read should answer all your questions with coding examples http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Masterpage-Javascript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your links including the javascript in the  sections of your code are pointing to he correct spot.  If you have FireBug you can also click on the 'Scipts' tab any verify that all of your js is loaded.  That would be the first think I would check at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `javascript` files are not referencing correctly after it goes live.
So make sure all your `js` and `css` file are reference to the correct path.

```
eg.http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.tabs.js
```